# Add a custom field to index results

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I have added a custom field to s template called Search Summary. It shows up in the index with Luke. But It is not in the results data. How can I add it to the results data, so I can then bind it to my search results page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search across a custom field, you would need to add a custom *IComputedIndexField*

but if values shows up in the index with Luke then your field is indexed.

i think you can do that:

create a new class inherit from SearchResultItem, and add a new propertie to your class to get the value of your custom field example:

```
[IndexField("Name of the field in Luke")]
public string PropertieName{get;set;}
```

replace SearchResultItem in your Query by the Name of your new Class like this:

```
SearchContext.GetQueryable<MyNewClassName>().Where(x=>x.PropertieName==Value);
```

Comment: Your information led to me that I was already doing it right.I was able to filter on it. I was trying to show it on my results page. But to get that, I just need to turn the document back to a Item and then pull the field from that.


rptSearch.DataSource = results.Hits.Select(x => x.Document.GetItem());
                        rptSearch.DataBind();

Comment: I am having similar problem, document back to a Item to display a custom field, but I think its too resource consuming, anyone knows a better solution?
I think if we can add a field to document then its sorted, thanks.